# Can I access a Perl hash using a scalar variable for its name?

Tags: perl, variables, hash

I'm wondering if I can use a variable to access a hash.

For instance:

```
my $var = "nameOfHash";
my $nameOfHash{'foo'} = "bar";

print $var{'foo'};
```

In the above sample, the behavior I desire is for it to return the string "bar," but clearly my code isn't quite correct.

Comment: The key question is *what are you trying to do*? You have imagined a mechanism which, while it does exist in Perl, is very much frowned on for its arbitrary population of the symbol table. Once you have set up all of these hashes, how do you know what names they have? The usual solution to questions like this is to use a hash, which can work like a miniature private symbol table that you can conveniently query for the keys it contains. However it would be much better if you would explain the problem that you are trying to solve this way so that we can advise you better.

Answer (score 5):

Why do you need it? You can use a hash of hashes (HoH) instead:

```
my %hoh;
$hoh{nameOfHash}{foo} = 'bar';
print $hoh{nameOfHash}{foo};
```

See [Why it's stupid to `use a variable as a variable name'](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html) for an explanation of what's wrong with the original idea.

Comment: Thanks for responding, Choroba! Related question: how would I then get keys for the HoH to store as an array? I'd used to just do "@hashArray = keys %nameOfHash;" but now that it's stored under $hoh{nameOfHash}, I'm having difficulty finding the proper syntax? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use dereference: `keys %{ $hoh{$nameOfHash} }`.

Comment: That helps a lot. Many thanks, Choroba, for your great help in getting an amateur like me on the right track!